# Where to add website direcetion link in javascript (within chart slice)?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have been using google charts, and was wondering how do I add a link to another website, in my case I would like to have a link to a site if the user clicks on the slice of the cart (6.178) where should I add javascript code and what code?

Regards

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Metric', 'Score'],
          ['Uniqueness',     6.178],
          ['Other',      93.82]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Unique Identifiability',
          pieHole: 0.6,
          colors: ['#EE7023', '#808080']  
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('uniqueness'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try to attach an onclik event on your required div after the chart is drawed ?

Comment: should I I add onclick event inside this? <div id="uniqueness" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;</div></td>

Comment: Can you show us your chart html ?

Comment: I would, but it says that the code is too long to add here. What is the magic way of adding long codes here?

Answer (score 0):

add the sites you want to open to the data table.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Metric', 'Score', 'Site'],
  ['Uniqueness', 6.178, 'https://www.google.com/'],
  ['Other', 93.82, 'https://www.bing.com/']
]);
```

use a data view to hide the sites from the chart.

```
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1]);
```

then open the site on the chart's select event.

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();  // get selected slice

    // ensure something is selected
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      // open the site
      window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2), '_blank');
    }
  });
```

use the view to draw the chart.

```
  chart.draw(view, options);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Metric', 'Score', 'Site'],
    ['Uniqueness', 6.178, 'https://www.google.com/'],
    ['Other', 93.82, 'https://www.bing.com/']
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Unique Identifiability',
    pieHole: 0.6,
    colors: ['#EE7023', '#808080']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('uniqueness'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();  // get selected slice

    // ensure something is selected
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      // open the site
      //window.open(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2), '_blank');
      console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2));
    }
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="uniqueness"></div>
```

note: the site won't actually open from inside the snippet,
but should work fine from your page...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I copied your snippet, but it won't show any link or anything..

Comment: I will do that for sure. Perhaps for me not to make another post in this case.

Do you have any clue how can I take away one of the slice '%' so it shows only one slice score (trying to highlight one slice) and also how to get rid of 'Uniqueness and Other' label outside chart?

everything I have tried so far (by adjusting code) the chart disappears..